ABC: one word under multiple notes

z D D D|
w: Lorem ipsum|


How can I achieve that the word ipsum will be centered under the last two notes when I do not want to use hyphen (ip-sum)?

Not sure that helps as it's not abc but lilypond, but there you could achieve that effect by using a tie on those two notes which you could then make visible/invisible or dashed.

Looking at https://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.0#lyrics it seems that almost anything is possible, except the thing you're asking about. Maybe it has been considered bad practice, or just not considered at all, because nobody has had that need before. I certainly prefer to see hyphens marked clearly.

@haxor789 Even if notes are tied, abc seems to attach the lyrics "syllable" to either the first or the second note, but the syllable cannot be shared by both notes equally. Well it's not really a syllable, it's a multi-syllable word, the OP just wants to glue the syllables together without a hyphen. It's possible to place a lot of text under a single note, but it's not possible to put multiple notes over a single syllable. I assume this is a restriction of the underlying data model, it's just designed that way.

ABC is a text based notation standard, not a musical typesetting system. ABC is not intended to be a format to be rendered to a graphical score, but actually an alternative to graphical scores. This means that to get from ABC to a graphical score you’ll need a piece of software to translate the information content. But as ABC does by design not require a lot of the information relevant to graphical scores the amount of control you’ll have over the output is quite limited.
Now, what you are looking for is called a melisma. In ABC notation you notate a melisma using *, so you can do:

z D D D |
w: Lorem ipsum * |

But note that while the official ABC specification states that * is a skipped note in lyrics it does not in any way impose how this is supposed to look in graphical output (as ABC does not care about graphical output). This means that the software you use might understand that on such a melisma the next note can be placed closer to the first than the lyrics allow. But that depends on the capabilities of the used software.
If you use abc2ly for example the * will turn into _, which will by Lilypond be correctly interpreted:

abcm2ps on the other hand will produce:

So the output will really depend on the software. Instead of * you can also use _, which should produce a line:

which is probably better than nothing. But really as ABC is a notation to represent music, not musical notation you cannot expect to get full amount of control over the rendering. If you want to actually produce graphical scores and do want to have that control over the rendering you should probably use something else, such es Lilypond or a graphical notation software (but it is important to know that not all notation software supports this feature. In e.g. MuseScore you can do melismas with an extension line totally fine, but you cannot really to it without a line, unless you leave a space and manually drag the syllable in the position you want).
EDIT: Also note that for the sake of not needing a hyphen sophisticated notation programs will actually not print the hyphen if by doing that the syllables can be placed closer together. So using an adequate software the software should be able to decide quite well if placing a hyphen makes sense in some place or if it doesn’t. E.g. this in Lilypond
{
 r8 d'8 d'8 d'8
} \addlyrics {
  Lorem ip -- sum
}

will be rendered as

while this
{
  d'1 d' d'
} \addlyrics {
  Lorem ip -- sum
}

will employ a dash:


Yep, you are right, abc is notation and not typesetting, thanks for clarification. I use ChordPro abc-directive and I just learned it uses abc2svg for rendering. I already tried * and _ for lyrics, but result is not good. So I'll use hyphens at the end.

I would argue that the OP is not attempting to notate a melisma, because obviously the "sum" syllable is supposed to be sung on the last note, and so the note is not "skipped". The OP actually does have two distinct syllables, but just wants to control their graphical layout on a level of detail that's outside the abc notation system's domain.

@piiperiReinstateMonica Yes, I noticed this too, which is why I added an edit. Still, the musical concept the OP talks about is a melisma, even though a melisma should not be used for what he actually wants.

The fact that “Lorem” has two syllables makes the OP's intention even less clear to me.
